# How to show color only to the first li?

Tags: css

I have a list inside a list and I would only like to have the first
LI with background color .

How can I get the first li to show the background color?

CSS

```
.selected {
    background-color: #C8C8C8;
}
.right {  
    position: relative;
    left: 15px;  
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="nav_main>
    <li class="fullChild selected" id="menuBranch">
            <a class="opener"></a>


                <a c href="test.cfm?branch" onclick="changeClass('branch')" >Branch</a>

            <ul>
                <cfset variables.dept_id = "" />
                <cfif isdefined( "url.dept_id" )>
                    <cfset variables.dept_id = url.dept_id />
                </cfif>
                <cfoutput query="GetDeptNum_branch">
                    <cfif GetDeptNum_branch.dept_id is variables.dept_id>
                        <li class="right"><a class="selected">#dept_name#</a></li></span>

                    <cfelse>
                                <li class="right" ><a href="test.cfm?dept_id=#dept_id#">#dept_name#</a></li></span>
                    </cfif>
                </cfoutput>
            </ul>
        </li>
</div>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp Try li:first-child{} in your CSS

Comment: The first `li` as in `<li class="fullChild selected" id="menuBranch">`? or first item in each list?

Comment: FYI, your outer list is missing a `<ul>` or `<ol>` container.  `<li>`s are meant to have a parent element.

Comment: The markup is invalid in several ways. If you are using some preprocessor or server-side technology elements instead of just HTML and CSS, you should tag the question with its name or, better, just show the generated HTML (unless it is *essential* where it comes from).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#nav_main li:first-child{background:red;}
```

Here you can find everything you need to know:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by the following way.

```
  ul > li:first-child {
      background: red;
    }
```